# Inject all class that implement and interface ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a base interface called `IBaseService` which I implement in many classes and I want to inject all classes that implement `IBaseService`.

Here is an example of my code:

```
public interface IBaseService
{
    Task<bool> Create();
}
    
public class EstadoService : IBaseService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IRepository<Estado> _repository;
        
    public EstadoService()
    {
    }
        
    public EstadoService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper, IRepository<Estado> repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repository = repository;
    }
        
    public async Task<bool> Create()
    {
        // Create Logic
    } 
}
    
public static object AddServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
 /*
   typeof(IBaseService).Assembly.GetTypes()                          
      .Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterface(typeof(IBaseService).Name) != 
       null).ToList().ForEach(appCoreService => 
       services.AddScoped(Activator.CreateInstance(appCoreService,)));
 */
    var items = typeof(IBaseService).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass && 
         x.GetInterface(nameof(IBaseService)) == typeof(IBaseService));
            
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
         string _name = item.FullName;
         Type t = Type.GetType(_name);
                    
         var instance = (IBaseService) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    
         services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IBaseService), instance, ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
     }
            
     return services;
}

public class EstadoController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IEstadoService _estado;

        public EstadoController(IEstadoService estado)
        {
            _estado = estado;
        }

        [HttpPost("add-estado")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddEstado(EstadoRegisterDto registerEstadoDto)
        {
            await _estado.Create(registerEstadoDto);

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

It looks fine, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Base on your code and the question... what kind of operation your're strggling of ? When register service in `IServiceCollection` or when you want to take all implemented of base type as normal using ?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: Hi, the problem is when I register the service.  I have not been able to instantiate the class by its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see you just want to add services that inherit `IBaseService` interface to dependency injection.

In not dynamically scenario to add a service to dependency injection you have to do it like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IEstadoService, EstadoService>();
```

If you put it like this in your code this won't work because `EstadoService` does not implement `IEstadoService` and the `class` and `interface` are not related.

In your controller to access to the services your injecting `IEstadoService` so, to get this working the first you need to do is:

in `IEstadoService` inherit from `IBaseService` like this:

```
public interface IEstadoService: IBaseService 
{
    // code here...
}
```

and in `EstadoService` inherit from `IEstadoService` like this:

```
public class EstadoService: IEstadoService
{
    // code here...
}
```

in this case you can add dependency injection dynamically like this:

```
    public static object AddServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var list = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterface(typeof(IBaseService).Name) != null && !mytype.IsInterface)
                .ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            services.AddScoped(item.GetInterface($"I{item.Name}"), item);
        }

        return services;
    }
```

The assembly list will have all services that inherit `IBaseService` in this case the list will have `EstadoService`.

As `item` in `foreach` loop is a `Type` we can call `item.GetInterface($"I{item.Name}")` which will result in `interface` object of type of `IEstadoService`

Like this it will work for all services that are implementing `IBaseService`

Answer (score 2):

For the register operation, fix it a bit like this

```
// Register on Startup
var items = typeof(IBaseService).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass && 
        x.GetInterface(nameof(IBaseService)) == typeof(IBaseService)).ToArray();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IBaseService), item, ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
}

// Using
public IActionResult TestInjection([FromServices] IEnumerable<IBaseService> estadoService)
{
    // Place a debugger here to see the result
    var allImplementedServices = estadoService.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I just test the code again... and clip a short [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K6pVKDMzVE37ojmENtMhnoBMACZwJiCQ/view?usp=sharing)... hope this help

Comment: How do you Instantiate all the method that are in the class EstadoService from the controller taking into consideration that you are using IEnumerable<IBaseService>. IE: estado.Create()

Comment: The purpose of this process is to dynamically register and using all type that implement `IBaseService`, which mean we will have access to whatever method that was declared on `IBaseService`, not the `EstadoService`. If we need to use some method of type `EstadoService `, check on the instance (like a foreach on IEnumerable injection as in sample above) and cast the object back to `EstadoService ` then call it.